# Specify default page for Storybook

Tags: storybook

I have storybook in my React app, and for some reason when i run `yarn storybook` it's always open the same story (it's automatically select `selectedKind` and `selectedStory`) . How can i manually select default story?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Kind and Story are selected based on the URL query parameters (i.e. `http://localhost:9001/?selectedKind=Component&selectedStory=default` will select the `Component` kind and `default` story). If you don't have any URL parameters, then storybook will choose the *first* story in the list (which is the first story loaded via however you have storybook configured).

If you just want to choose the first story in the list, then load you story files in a specific order in your `loadStories` function in `.storybook/config.js` file.

---

If, however, you want to *always* force the same story to be selected, then follow the instructions below.

The best way to do this would be to use the Storybook's addonAPI.
Here is an example that worked for me (with a safeguard so you don't get stuck on the same story forever):

```
// .storybook/addons.js
import addonAPI from '@storybook/addons';

let firstLoad = true;
addonAPI.register('my-organisation/my-addon', (storybookAPI) => {
  storybookAPI.onStory((kind, story) => {
    // when you enter a story, if you are just loading storybook up, default to a specific kind/story. 
    if (firstLoad) {
      firstLoad = false; // make sure to set this flag to false, otherwise you will never be able to look at another story.
      storybookAPI.selectStory('FirstKind', 'default story');
    }
  });
});
```

With that snippet, no matter what story you end up on based on the URL, you can select the first story to land on.

You can read more about the storybook addonAPI here: https://storybook.js.org/addons/api/
I would probably allow an additional query parameter in the URL to force the kind+story from the URL to be chosen.

Note: there may be an existing addon that provides this functionality, but a quick search yielded no viable results.

Comment:  for simply requiring the story you want to default to first in config.js

Comment: If you're using `main.js` variant of the config, you can also place it first in the `stories` array, like `stories : ["../src/index.stories.mdx", "..src/**/*.stories.(tsx|mdx)"]`.

Comment: Beware, this solution can appear to fail if you have a mixture of CSF and old format stories.

Comment: @Nucleon great answer!

Answer (score 33):

With `storybook v6`, just pust default page's mdx to the first position in `stories` field;

Demo

```js
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports={
  stories:[
    '../packages/intro.stories.mdx', // default page
    '../packages/**/*.stories.mdx'
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer since Storybook 6 was released. I thought briefly that it didn't work but that was due to custom story sorting. This is a great solution for Storybook 6 and above and should become the default answer.

Comment: Totally agree: and quite unfortunately this is not immediately obvious from their documentation, although they did mention that import order matters :) thank you!

Comment: Works for Angular Projects as well 

Answer (score 5):

You can fix this with `storySort`, I had this issue but I figured it out.

To choose a file or component as your landing file, you can specify in your `.storybook/preview.js` file.
Just like this:

```
    export const parameters = {
      .........,
      options: {
        storySort: {
          order: ['Components', ['Forms', ['Select']]],
        },
      },
    };
```

[image: Sample of my component library]

To sort stories alphabetically, you can do this

```
    export const parameters = {
      .........,
      options: {
        storySort: (a, b) => a[1].id.localeCompare(b[1].id),
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

To select a specific story on load, if a story is not specified, use the following addon

```js
// .storybook/addons.js
import { STORIES_CONFIGURED, STORY_MISSING } from '@storybook/core-events'
import addonAPI from '@storybook/addons'

addonAPI.register('my-organisation/first-page', storybookAPI => {
  storybookAPI.on(STORIES_CONFIGURED, (kind, story) => {
    if (storybookAPI.getUrlState().path === '/story/*') {
      storybookAPI.selectStory('Kind', 'Story')
    }
  })
  storybookAPI.on(STORY_MISSING, (kind, story) => {
    storybookAPI.selectStory('Kind', 'Story')
  })
})
```

replacing `Kind`, `Story` with your desired story. Testing the URL for `/story/*` stops changing the page if a specific story is requested and the second listener works for the case where a missing story, or incorrect URL is supplied. Unfortunately, at this time, there's no API to select the docs page.

Answer (score -1):

In our case storybook was always selecting the first story with a root (even with story loading order adjusted), but we wanted an introduction without a root to be first. It's a poor mans solution because you see the redirect visually, but the best we could do was:

```js
// ./addons/default-story/register.js
import { SET_GLOBALS, STORY_PREPARED, STORY_MISSING } from '@storybook/core-events'
import { addons } from '@storybook/addons';

addons.register('your-org/default-story', api => {
  const emitter = addons.getChannel();

  let shouldRedirect = false;

  emitter.on(SET_GLOBALS, (kind, story) => {
    if (!window.location.search) {
      shouldRedirect = true;
    }
  })

  emitter.on(STORY_PREPARED, (kind, story) => {
    if (shouldRedirect) {
      api.selectStory("Introduction", "Introduction")
    }
    shouldRedirect = false
  })


  emitter.on(STORY_MISSING, (kind, story) => {
    api.selectStory('Introduction', 'Introduction')
  })
})
```

Ps, load this in your main.js file:

```js
  addons: [
    "./addons/default-story/register.js",
```